# Creating a math keyboard using React and MathQuill

Tags: reactjs, math, keyboard, mathquill

I have been trying to create a math keyboard using mathquill, like the one in the screen below, where you can insert math symbols and write over them to answer a question. Found some solutions, but none using react that do not require ReactDOM. Does anyone know how can I achieve something like that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: I just added a couple of screens with the codes I worked on. The first uses ReatDOM, when I try that code on a class component I don't get the input area to display the math equations after clicking on them. The last screen is an HTML code.

Comment: Please do not use images to share your code.

Answer (score 1):

Creating math keyboard functionality can be done with [MathKeyboardEngine](https://github.com/mathkeyboardengine/mathkeyboardengine) in combination with any LaTeX typesetting library. So if there is a LaTeX typesetting library for React that does not require ReactDOM (like you stated you want) then you can use it in combination with MathKeyboardEngine.

- Katex has a few packages for React, for example [react-latex](https://github.com/zzish/react-latex) or [react-katex](https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-katex), of which the first seems to not use ReactDOM.
- MathJax also has React packages, for example [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax).

I’m curious whether this will work. (I have no experience with React.)